# macOS: Keyboard shortcut for switching between two apps in split-view

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut, split-view

This has been asked in the past, but the last time this question was asked was in 2015 and I hope things have changed in the meanwhile.

I'm essentially using two (different) apps side-by-side in macOS split-view, and I would like to switch between those two apps using a keyboard shortcut.

Is there any way to achieve this? Or any way to program such a shortcut?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Isn't the regular Cmd + Tab working?

Comment: thanks! :) unfortunately not reliably, I usually have this set-up multiplied over 2-3 windows (so each window has one terminal and one editor) switching between the two might take me to any one of those terminal/editor instances in any one of those three windows